# Ubuntu can't connect usb Wifi

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

My motherboard has only wired network adapter. I am trying to connect through wifi usb. System detects the networks, tries to connect, but authentication always fail (wrong password is no option, I am sure the password is correct). System outputs:

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 0bda:c811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
```

Journalctl (I masked the beginning of my MAC Address. It seems strange that it tries to connect to two different MAC Address (the last digit of it):

```
journalctl -g wlx502b730c2843
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3073] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: starting connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' (b5f86a10-e2ec-4e3b-a5e9-e38f7a834fb9)
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3074] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3075] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3077] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) access point 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3077] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3078] sup-iface[58211749e48709ad,1,wlx502b730c2843]: wps: type pbc start...
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3083] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3084] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.3085] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: WPS-CANCEL
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: SME: Trying to authenticate with (MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=5180 MHz)
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404864.7870] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Aug 30 11:14:24 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (try 1/3)
Aug 30 11:14:25 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (try 2/3)
Aug 30 11:14:26 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (try 3/3)
Aug 30 11:14:27 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authentication with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 timed out
Aug 30 11:14:27 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Aug 30 11:14:27 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404867.8433] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Aug 30 11:14:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404877.9144] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 30 11:14:38 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink"
Aug 30 11:14:38 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: SME: Trying to authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 30 11:14:38 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40
Aug 30 11:14:38 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (try 1/3)
Aug 30 11:14:38 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404878.6937] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 30 11:14:39 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (try 2/3)
Aug 30 11:14:40 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (try 3/3)
Aug 30 11:14:41 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authentication with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 timed out
Aug 30 11:14:41 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Aug 30 11:14:41 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404881.7989] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Aug 30 11:14:50 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <warn>  [1693404890.0463] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Aug 30 11:14:50 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404890.0463] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:14:50 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <warn>  [1693404890.0465] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink'
Aug 30 11:14:50 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404890.0466] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:00 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4895] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: starting connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' (b5f86a10-e2ec-4e3b-a5e9-e38f7a834fb9)
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4895] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4897] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4899] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) access point 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4899] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4900] sup-iface[58211749e48709ad,1,wlx502b730c2843]: wps: type pbc start...
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4904] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4905] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.4906] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: WPS-CANCEL
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: SME: Trying to authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=5180 MHz)
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404901.7834] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> authenticating
Aug 30 11:15:01 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (try 1/3)
Aug 30 11:15:02 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (try 2/3)
Aug 30 11:15:03 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 (try 3/3)
Aug 30 11:15:04 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authentication with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:44 timed out
Aug 30 11:15:04 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Aug 30 11:15:04 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404904.7716] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Aug 30 11:15:14 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404914.8396] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Aug 30 11:15:15 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink"
Aug 30 11:15:15 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: SME: Trying to authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=2437 MHz)
Aug 30 11:15:15 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authenticate with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40
Aug 30 11:15:15 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404915.6257] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Aug 30 11:15:15 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (try 1/3)
Aug 30 11:15:16 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (try 2/3)
Aug 30 11:15:17 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: send auth to MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 (try 3/3)
Aug 30 11:15:18 mlmachine kernel: wlx502b730c2843: authentication with MY:MAC:ADD:58:a9:ef:40 timed out
Aug 30 11:15:19 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Aug 30 11:15:19 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404919.1510] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Aug 30 11:15:27 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <warn>  [1693404927.0464] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Aug 30 11:15:27 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404927.0464] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:27 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <warn>  [1693404927.0466] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink'
Aug 30 11:15:27 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404927.0467] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 30 11:15:30 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 30 11:15:45 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 30 11:16:00 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
Aug 30 11:16:02 mlmachine NetworkManager[991]: <info>  [1693404962.1823] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 30 11:16:15 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[993]: wlx502b730c2843: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
```

dmesg output that seems related:

```
[    6.966645] Call Trace:
[    6.966646] rtw_8821cu 1-4.1:1.0: Firmware version 24.11.0, H2C version 12
[    6.966656]  <TASK>
[    6.966660]  ? update_load_avg+0x82/0x810
[    6.966669]  ? newidle_balance+0x325/0x4b0
[    6.966675]  rtw8821c_query_rx_desc+0x147/0x2f0 [rtw88_8821c]
[    6.966684]  rtw_usb_rx_handler+0x114/0x1d0 [rtw88_usb]
[    6.966691]  process_one_work+0x225/0x430
[    6.966698]  worker_thread+0x50/0x3e0
[    6.966703]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[    6.966710]  kthread+0xe9/0x110
[    6.966716]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[    6.966721]  ret_from_fork+0x2c/0x50
[    6.966728]  </TASK>
[    6.966730] Modules linked in: rtw88_8821cu(+) iommu_v2 rtw88_8821c drm_buddy gpu_sched rtw88_usb snd_seq_midi rtw88_core drm_ttm_helper snd_seq_midi_event kvm ttm snd_rawmidi mac80211 irqbypass drm_display_helper crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni snd_seq polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel cec sha512_ssse3 aesni_intel rc_core snd_seq_device crypto_simd cfg80211 snd_timer drm_kms_helper cryptd i2c_algo_bit libarc4 gigabyte_wmi wmi_bmof rapl snd syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt k10temp soundcore ccp joydev input_leds mac_hid msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport efi_pstore dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid hid nvme crc32_pclmul r8169 ahci nvme_core i2c_piix4 xhci_pci libahci realtek xhci_pci_renesas video nvme_common wmi
```

---

Journalctl after installing the driver @ChanganAuto linked in comments.

```
Aug 31 14:17:05 mlmachine sudo[12633]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 31 14:17:07 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502227.4162] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 31 14:17:07 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502227.4162] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 31 14:17:25 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16
Aug 31 14:17:31 mlmachine kernel: RTW: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlx502b730c2843)  fw_state=0x00000008
Aug 31 14:17:32 mlmachine sudo[12639]:  corisco : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/corisco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service networking restart
Aug 31 14:17:32 mlmachine sudo[12639]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Aug 31 14:17:32 mlmachine sudo[12639]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 31 14:17:38 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
Aug 31 14:17:38 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 ignore list count incremented to 4, ignoring for 120 seconds
Aug 31 14:17:38 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Aug 31 14:17:38 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502258.5016] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Aug 31 14:17:38 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502258.5017] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> disconnected
Aug 31 14:17:43 mlmachine sudo[12645]:  corisco : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/corisco ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/service network restart
Aug 31 14:17:43 mlmachine sudo[12645]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=1000)
Aug 31 14:17:43 mlmachine sudo[12645]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Aug 31 14:17:48 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502268.5099] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 31 14:17:48 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502268.5099] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 31 14:18:01 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16
Aug 31 14:18:03 mlmachine systemd[1671]: Started app-gnome-gnome\x2dwifi\x2dpanel-12651.scope - Application launched by gnome-shell.
Aug 31 14:18:03 mlmachine dbus-daemon[1146]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.316' (uid=1000 pid=12651 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-control-center wifi" label="unconfined")
Aug 31 14:18:03 mlmachine systemd[1]: Starting systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service...
Aug 31 14:18:03 mlmachine dbus-daemon[1146]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug 31 14:18:03 mlmachine systemd[1]: Started systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service.
Aug 31 14:18:03 mlmachine gnome-shell[1989]: Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0xc00004
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6583] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: starting connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' (b5f86a10-e2ec-4e3b-a5e9-e38f7a834fb9)
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6583] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="b5f86a10-e2ec-4e3b-a5e9-e38f7a834fb9" name="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" pid=12651 uid=1000 result="success"
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6584] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6585] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6586] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6587] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) access point 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' has security, but secrets are required.
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6587] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6588] sup-iface[95f59c0dca04d725,3,wlx502b730c2843]: wps: type pbc start...
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6592] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6594] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] Config: added 'ssid' value 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink'
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-70:86400'
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK WPA-PSK-SHA256'
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6595] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: WPS-CANCEL
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6695] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 31 14:18:05 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502285.6695] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> scanning
Aug 31 14:18:14 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502294.0866] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: scanning -> inactive
Aug 31 14:18:14 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502294.0866] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> inactive
Aug 31 14:18:19 mlmachine gnome-shell[1989]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaWindowActorX11>:0x5566686b1290] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 31 14:18:19 mlmachine gnome-shell[1989]: Can't update stage views actor <unnamed>[<MetaSurfaceActorX11>:0x556666ef95b0] is on because it needs an allocation.
Aug 31 14:18:20 mlmachine kernel: RTW: wlx502b730c2843- hw port(0) mac_addr =50:2b:73:0c:28:43
Aug 31 14:18:20 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=5180 MHz)
Aug 31 14:18:20 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Aug 31 14:18:20 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
Aug 31 14:18:20 mlmachine kernel: RTW: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlx502b730c2843)  fw_state=0x00000008
Aug 31 14:18:30 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <warn>  [1693502310.9301] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Aug 31 14:18:30 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502310.9302] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:30 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502310.9303] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Aug 31 14:18:30 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <warn>  [1693502310.9304] device (wlx502b730c2843): Activation: failed for connection 'HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink'
Aug 31 14:18:30 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502310.9305] device (wlx502b730c2843): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 31 14:18:33 mlmachine systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Deactivated successfully.
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine kernel: RTW: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlx502b730c2843)  fw_state=0x00000008
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine kernel: RTW: wlx502b730c2843- hw port(0) mac_addr =50:2b:73:0c:28:43
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502317.6101] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: inactive -> associating
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502317.6101] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: inactive -> associating
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502317.6101] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: associating -> disconnected
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502317.6101] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: associating -> disconnected
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502317.7133] device (wlx502b730c2843): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 31 14:18:37 mlmachine NetworkManager[1222]: <info>  [1693502317.7134] device (p2p-dev-wlx502b730c2843): supplicant management interface state: disconnected -> inactive
Aug 31 14:18:44 mlmachine wpa_supplicant[1223]: wlx502b730c2843: Reject scan trigger since one is already pending
```

Tried to connect using wpa_supplicant in command line, the log file:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
nl80211: kernel reports: Match already configured
(many times....)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-1 retry=1
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-1 retry=1
(many times....)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-1 retry=1
wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=5180 MHz)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0
wlx502b730c2843: Authentication with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 timed out.
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 reason=3 locally_generated=1
BSSID 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:40 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=2462 MHz)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=5180 MHz)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
BSSID 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 ignore list count incremented to 3, ignoring for 60 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink"
wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:40 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=2462 MHz)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=2462 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=-1 ch_width=40 MHz cf1=2452 cf2=0
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
BSSID 08:f4:58:a9:ef:40 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=2 duration=25 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink"
wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:40 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=2462 MHz)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=2462 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=-1 ch_width=40 MHz cf1=2452 cf2=0
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
BSSID 08:f4:58:a9:ef:40 ignore list count incremented to 3, ignoring for 60 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=3 duration=40 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink"
wlx502b730c2843: Trying to associate with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 (SSID='HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink' freq=5180 MHz)
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-STARTED-CHANNEL-SWITCH freq=5180 ht_enabled=1 ch_offset=1 ch_width=80 MHz cf1=5210 cf2=0
wlx502b730c2843: Authentication with 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 timed out.
BSSID 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 ignore list count incremented to 4, ignoring for 120 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 reason=3 locally_generated=1
BSSID 08:f4:58:a9:ef:44 ignore list count incremented to 5, ignoring for 600 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="HUAWEI-K4QXJF_HiLink" auth_failures=4 duration=61 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-ASSOC-REJECT status_code=1
BSSID 00:00:00:00:00:00 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=CORE type=WORLD
wlx502b730c2843: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-FAILED ret=-16 retry=1
```

Comment: "*System outputs: ...*" -- The `lsusb` command (which is over-relied on IMO) only informs you of completed USB connections, and little else. You need to review the entire syslog for USB connection & driver installation. After you plug in the USB-WiFI adapter, use the `dmeg` command. Pay attention for any "firmware" messages.  BTW you neglect to mention the exact make & model of the adapter.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1463799

Comment: I edited the question to add the info you asked (about dmesg and drivers).

Comment: Installed driver as @ChanganAuto said... but no luck.